# Way to know browser refresh or F5 has been hit

Tags: javascript, refresh, dom-events

I am looking for a way to identify if user refreshes a page or hits <kbd>F5</kbd> using Javascript (more specifically prototype Javascript library)...

I am coding an application that needs to record the number of refresh(es) or <kbd>F5</kbd> on a web page for statistics purposes. A refresh or <kbd>F5</kbd> in this case means the user is skipping or escaping doing his work on the page :) So the statistics helps them find how many of them are doing it :).. Kind of policing...

Comment: Does clicking in the addressbar and hitting enter count as a refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following piece of code on *each* page (only then you can differ between refreshing/navigating):

```
var last = localStorage["lastPage"] || "",
    current = location.href;

if(last === current) { // last page is the same as this page
    // this is a refresh
]

localStorage["lastPage"] = current;
```

It only differs between navigating on the same domain and not doing so (i.e. going to another website and then going back to the same page counts as a refresh).

Comment: Incorporated your idea into my answer, storing the address as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Upon loading the page, save the time-stamp into a persistent storage (either [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) or cookies).

Before that, check if the time-stamp was already there. Then compare the stamps as needed.

```
var MIN_TIME = 60e3 // 60 seconds

var key = location.href
var now = Date.now()
var previousVisit = localStorage.getItem(key) || now

localStorage.setItem(key, now)

if (now - previousVisit < MIN_TIME) {
    alert('You lazy sloth!')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a much simpler solution: [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: It will be triggered if you simply close the tab/window.

Comment: Yes, but the requirements were «means the user is skipping or escaping doing his work on the page», so I'm guessing it applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for keycode = 116 , and detect the keypress event.

Comment: I think he asks about how to detect a page refresh, not just detecting the F5 key...