# How do I get a div to appear after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a calculator made up of two parts, the entry and then the results. The results link to a google sheet and need a couple of seconds to run.

Initially I had this working by making it two steps - when the button was clicked the results appeared on another page - which worked.

I now need to try and get both on the same page.

Is there a way I can keep the div #results hidden, until the page is when the button is clicks refreshed?

https://codepen.io/jameswill77/pen/PoROgvM

```
<div class="calculator" data-calc-id="Lyh7nBH9MiharKMDu" data-type="framed"></div>
<script src="https://scripts.convertcalculator.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>

<div id="results" class="results-style">

<div class="calculator" data-calc-id="ogNjyteRSgnEHv6Ps" data-type="framed"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://scripts.convertcalculator.com/embed.js"></script>
<div class="calculator" data-calc-id="Lyh7nBH9MiharKMDu" data-type="framed"></div>
<script src="https://scripts.convertcalculator.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>

<div id="results" class="results-style">

<div class="calculator" data-calc-id="ogNjyteRSgnEHv6Ps" data-type="framed"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, there's [Way to know browser refresh or F5 has been hit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8531621/215552), but I would think there would be a better way of doing it than making your users wait and refresh or refreshing with `window.location.reload()`

Comment: But please [edit] your question to include all relevant code as a [mre], not just a link to somewhere else that will get stale and ruin the question after a few months.